# Why I do not get the right answer

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, ampl, glpk

I think logically the following code is right but I get the wrong answer:

**.mod file:**

```
set R := {1,2};
set D1 := {1,2,4,5};
set P1 := {1,2,3,4,5};
var V{D1,R}, binary;
param Ud{D1,R} ; 
param  U{P1,R} ;

minimize obj{p in D1, r in R}: V[p,r] * (Ud[p,r]+ sum{j in P1: j!=p} U[j,r]); 


 s.t. a10{ r in R }: sum{p in D1} V[p,r]=2 ;
```

**.dat file:**

```
 param  Ud: 1  2:=
1     -10     -6
2      -20   -4
4      1      -10
5       -4     -4;   




param  U: 1      2  :=
1          -8.1  -3
2          -6.8  -8
3          -7.2   1
4          -16     -4
5           -6.8   -4;
```

Basically for each r and for two p , I want to minimize `(Ud[p,r] + sum{j in P: j!=p} U[j,r])`

But it always give me `V[1,r]=v[5,r]=1` even if `V[2,r]` minimize obj function.

I except to get `V[2,r]=1` because `-20 + (-8.1-7.2 -16-6.8)` is the most negative.

Comment: Is P1 meant to be P?

Comment: Is `v{P,R}` meant to be `V[p,r]`?

Comment: Please help us out by cleaning up your code and explaining better what your model is trying to accomplish. I more descriptive title would help, too. Finally, it would be best if you can post a minimal, compilable code (including data file) so we can try running it for ourselves.

Comment: @LarrySnyder610 agreed in the last line, and I think `V{p,r}` for the declaration.

Comment: There's also a missing semicolon in the third line.

Comment: @LarrySnyder610 is it good enough?

Comment: @user9272398 does this run without error messages when you try to run it in AMPL?

Comment: yes there is no error, I just get wrong answer

Comment: What answer and objective function value are you expecting to see?

Comment: @GeoffreyBrent please see edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax for the objective function is incorrect; it should be

```
minimize obj: sum {p in D1, r in R} V[p,r] * (Ud[p,r]+ sum{j in P1: j != p} U[j,r]);
```

(Note the location of the colon (`:`), and the presence of the `sum`.) To be honest I'm not exactly sure what AMPL was doing in response to your objective function, but I would just treat the results as unpredictable.

With the revised objective function, the optimal solution is:

```
ampl: display V;
V :=
1 1   1
1 2   1
2 1   1
2 2   0
4 1   0
4 2   1
5 1   0
5 2   0
;
```

Comment: Thank you so I should sum on p as well, I understood what was wrong!

Comment: Yes. The objective function must be a single number (a scalar), so it is usually a sum. You had it structured more like a vector, or like a "for all".

Comment: huh, I didn't even realise it was possible to have an indexed OF in AMPL! Live and learn.

Comment: I know, me either. I suspect AMPL is treating it like it would if you just declare two separate objectives, except here there are lots. The AMPL book says "If a model declares more than one objective function, AMPL by default passes all of
them to the solver. Most solvers deal only with one objective function and usually select the first by default." So that's probably what's happening here.